# Proving multiplicitive properties of Euler's phi function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I'm currently working on this problem:

We know that if $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ are pair wise, relatively prime integers, then $\phi(m,n) = \phi(m) \times \phi(n)$ 
Prove by induction that if $m_1,...,m_r$ are pair-wise relatively prime positive integers, then $\phi(m_1\cdot m_r) = \phi(m_1)\cdot\cdot\cdot\phi(m_r).$

---

What I have so far:

For our base case, let $r=2$

Then $\phi(m_1\cdot m_r)=\phi(m_1)\cdot\cdot\cdot\phi(m_r)$
is the same as $\phi(m_1\cdot m_2)=\phi(m_1)\phi(m_2)$ which is the given property, so we know that the base case holds.

---

The inductive step is what I'm not sure about. Any pointers regarding how I could proceed?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\varphi(n)=\left|\mathbb{Z}/(n\mathbb{Z})^*\right|$.
 Assuming that $m,n$ are coprime, by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) we have
$$ \mathbb{Z}/(mn\mathbb{Z})^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}/(m\mathbb{Z})^*\times \mathbb{Z}/(n\mathbb{Z})^*$$
hence $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\cdot\varphi(n)$, and if $m_1,\ldots,m_r$ are pairwise coprime,
$$\varphi\left(\prod_{k=1}^{r}m_k\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{r}\varphi(m_k).$$

---

Alternative way: we may use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to show that in general
$$\varphi(n) = n\cdot\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) $$
hence the multiplicativity of $\varphi$ follows from the fact that coprime integers have disjoint sets of prime divisors.